# Can't install drivers for my Broadcom 43142

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm a newbie when it cames to linux and after some research I've decided that Mint was the best option but I'm having many problems trying to install the drivers for my wireless card that is a Broadcom 43142.

I was searching on the internet for several days trying to fix my problem, but with no change, it still doesn't work...

On the terminal I wrote this just to confirm the Wireless Card:

```
lspci -vnn | grep 14e4
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

With that info I've searched for a Broadcom Wireless Table and I've found that the package for my Broadcom is the *bcmwl-kernel-source*

But when I run the command: `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  bcmwl-kernel-source : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed
  libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
  libc6:i386 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And I've tried the command `sudo apt-get -f install` and more errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1734 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3937 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7299 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  locales
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 155573 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-15_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-15) over (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-15_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/update-locale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-15_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And again, nothing seems to work..

Can you please help me? I want to leave windows and stay only with Linux but I need to solve this first...

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not support Linux Mint here - it's Ubuntu and official derivatives only. Should you choose Ubuntu in the future, please do not hesitate to come back.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider my working response for **Cinnamon x64 "Rebecca"** here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182950/bcm43142-wont-work-with-mint-17-1-cinnamon-x64/195691#195691

> Here is the answer for **Cinnamon x64 "Rebecca"** solving **without
>   need of an internet connection**:
>
> - Open the DVD / USB with the Linux install.
> - Go to /pool/main/e/eglibc.
> - Install both packages. (*libc6-dev* & *libc-dev-bin*)
> - Go to /pool/main/b/bcmwl.
> - Install package. (*bcmwl-kernel-source*).
>
> **Note**: If you don't find the packages there, search them elsewhere in /pool. (updates might change paths)